xrandr --addmode gives error BadMatch, worked before
In Ubuntu prior 24.04, X11, I could use this code to set screen resolution:
cvt 3200 1800
xrandr --newmode "3200x1800_60.00"  492.00  3200 3456 3800 4400  1800 1803 1808 1865 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP1 "3200x1800_60.00"
xrandr --output eDP1 --mode "3200x1800_60.00"

However, now I am getting error
xrandr --addmode eDP1 "3200x1800_60.00"
X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request: 140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request: 18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request: 39
Current serial number in output stream: 40

So I cannot raise resolution of screen in Immersed VR. How to resolve the error please?
